# How to know when a file is closed

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a script that copies a section of data from one file to another.  The destination file is shared among users. After the copy, I save and close the destination file and issue a an "Updated" message.

My Code:

```
...        
   Workbooks(CurrFile).Activate
   Worksheets(CurrHosp).Range("A1").Select
   Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
   TimeStamp = Now()
   ActiveSheet.Range("A5").Value = TimeStamp
   ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

   Workbooks(ModelFile).Close SaveChanges:=False
   Workbooks(CurrFile).Close SaveChanges:=True

   MsgBox ("Destination Updated")
Else
   MsgBox ("No Source File Selected")
End If

   Application.StatusBar = False
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Today, a user left her desk with the "Updated" message box open. This left the destination file (Currfile) in an open state preventing other users from updating it.

When does Excel actually close a file after issuing a Workbooks().Close statement?  Is it when the subroutine completes?
How can I detect it's really closed before I issue the "Updated" message box?

Comment: Is the VBA code located in the workbook you're trying to close?

Comment: No.  The source of the data to copy and the destination are two additional files.  3 files total.

Comment: Slip a `DoEvents` just before displaying the `MsgBox`, so as to let Excel handle the closure. You don't want to "detect that it's really closed", you just want to give Excel a chance to do its thing before you do something else (e.g. display a message box) - `DoEvents` will do exactly that.

Comment: @Mat's Mug, the DoEvents worked. If you want to put it in the form of an answer I'll accept it. Sorry it took so long to respond. It took a while to generate the appropriate test files.